# covering the whole body with page loader with css and javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page where users press buttons to process data and this takes up to 40 seconds so I wanted to make a loading page I used a CSS template but I don't know how to change the `background colour` on calling the div to show I tried this:

```js
$("#q12").click(function() {
  $("#q11").show();
  $("#content").css("background", "(136,136,136,0.2)");
});
```

where `#q12` is the button id and `#q11` is the div(loading animations) id and `#content` is the div I wrap the content of the page in and i can't simply replace the body color as it won't cover the content so is there anything i can add to the animation to hide the page and show the user that something is really loading as it's small and at the top centre of the page

here's the CSS

```css
#content{

margin-top : 4%;
margin-left : 18%;
margin-right : 2%;
margin-bottom : 6%;

}
.loading{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.obj{
  width: 9px;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  animation: loading 0.8s infinite;
}
.obj:nth-child(2){
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.obj:nth-child(3){
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.obj:nth-child(4){
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.obj:nth-child(5){
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.obj:nth-child(6){
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
.obj:nth-child(7){
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
.obj:nth-child(8){
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}


@keyframes loading {
  0%{
    height: 0;
  }
  50%{
    height: 70px;
  }
  100%{
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

I've never done preloaders or loading screens before and when I look at examples they only show the pure CSS not how it's called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you needed?

```js
$("#q12").click(function() {
  $("#q11").show();
});
```

```css
.page-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

#content {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-left: 18%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 6%;
  text-align: center;
}

#q11 {
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(136, 136, 136, 0.2);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.loading {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.obj {
  width: 9px;
  height: 70px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 3px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  animation: loading 0.8s infinite;
}

.obj:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}

.obj:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.obj:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}

.obj:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.obj:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

.obj:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

.obj:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 0.7s;
}

@keyframes loading {
  0% {
    height: 0;
  }
  50% {
    height: 70px;
  }
  100% {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <div id="content">
     content goes here
    </div>
    <button id="q12">Submit</button>
  </div>


  <!--     place at the end of body -->
  <div id="q11">
    <div class="loading">

      <div class="obj">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the javascript code runs only from the console. 
I have to run it in the console to work i mean.

Answer (score 0):

`(136,136,136,0.2)` isn't a valid property for `background`, but `rgba(136,136,136,0.2)` is.

```
<script>
  $("#q12").click(function() {
    $("#q11").show();
    $("#content").css("background", "rgba(136,136,136,0.2)");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: but this didn't override the content i want to hide everything in the page and show only the loader. 
thanks for your help.